# Executing user input from io.read()

Tags: lua

So I have a Lua code where I have a bunch of different functions in a file (as multiple scripts use them) and I want one to be able to execute some of them based on user input. So if the user inputs addUser() (one of my functions) then the code will run addUser(). Now, I know u can do it like

```
    var = io.read()
    if var == (some function) then
        (function)
    else
        if var == (some other function) then
```

Etc.

But I want a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the user input just the name of the function and then do

```
var = io.read()
if _G[var]~=nil then _G[var]() end
```

If you want to allow `foo()`, use

```
var = var:gsub("[%s()]","")
```

just after reading.

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. I'm just going to make a note (because I didn't really get  this part of it, probably cause I'm a bit tired) that what is imputed in io.read() is just the function name. So if the function is `bla()` then the input should just be `bla`

Comment: I'd rather test for `type(_G[var]) == "function"` than just `nil` if you're doing checks anyway.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, tables and user data may behave like functions if you set call metamethods.

Comment: Does anyone know of their is a way for me to close my question and mark it as being answered so that it won't get more replies?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov given that I am using other variables in the program, that is a very good idea. Not doing so could result in a normal variable being called as a function. Thanks.